# Migration from log4j 1.x to log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Hi I came across some code which is using log4j. I want to move to log4j2. 
From http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html I came to that log4j-1.2-api.jar can be used. I have following question :

1. In code I have a custom appender (as given in that link I should not use internals of class Appender) is that mean I can't use log4j-1.2-api.jar ?
2. I also want to use asyn logging feature of log4j2 . How do I do that using log4j-1.2-api.jar.

Answer (score 5):

1. Your custom appender may no longer work. Log4j2 has a lot of functionality, and depending on what your custom appender did, it could be that this functionality already exists in log4j2. You can ask on one of the mailing lists and if it is a function that could be useful for many users it may be added to log4j2.
2. To use the async loggers, you can either make all loggers async with a system property (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#AllAsync) or mix synchronous and async loggers with configuration (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#MixedSync-Async). Both should work when you drop in the log4j-1.2-api jar (in addition to the log4j-api and log4j-core jars, these two jars are always needed).

Answer (score 3):

There is a migration guide. I used it successfully.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

In `log4j2` everything is cofigured using a XML file (or more XML files, e. g. for your test directory). The file should be named `log4j2.xml`.

Comment: Can a .properties file be used instead?

Comment: @MengLu Yes .properties file can be used and should be named as log4j2.properties